# index out of bounds error because numel

Tags: matlab

It loops through until the last time and then I get an error "Attempted to access EQ_NUM(8); index out of bounds because
numel(EQ_NUM)=7."

```
N_NODE=8
N_PRE_DISP=2
DISP_NODE= [2 7]

EQ_NUM = 0;
for i = 1:N_PRE_DISP 
    NODE=DISP_NODE(i);
    EQ_NUM(NODE) = -i;
end

ROW = 0;
for i = 1:N_NODE
    if (EQ_NUM(i)==0)
        ROW = ROW+1;
        EQ_NUM(i)=ROW;
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop

```
EQ_NUM = 0;
for i = 1:N_PRE_DISP 
    NODE=DISP_NODE(i);
    EQ_NUM(NODE) = -i;
end
```

you create `EQ_NUM` with 7 elements; the highest value that `NODE` takes is the highest value in `DISP_NODE(1:2)` which is `7`.

In this loop

```
ROW = 0;
for i = 1:N_NODE
    if (EQ_NUM(i)==0)
        ROW = ROW+1;
        EQ_NUM(i)=ROW;
    end 
end
```

you loop over `i=1:8` and eventually try to execute `EQ_NUM(8)==0`.

You need to fix something, but I don't know what.  Possibly you think that Matlab arrays are indexed from 0, they're not, the first index into a Matlab array is 1.

Comment: how can I create EQ_NUM to have 8 elements?

Comment: At the risk of seeming unhelpful: the answer to your question can be found in the early pages of the introductory documentation.  Your time would be better spent reading that than asking a series of very basic questions here on SO.

Comment: I fixed my error.

    EQ_NUM = zeros(1,N_NODE);

    for i = 1:N_PRE_DISP
        NODE=DISP_NODE(i);
        EQ_NUM(NODE) = -i;   
    end
    ROW = 0;
    for i = 1:N_NODE
        if (EQ_NUM(i)==0)
        ROW = ROW+1;
        EQ_NUM(i)=ROW;
     end 
    end

Comment: thats not clear - I first dfined EQ_NUM as an array of zeros the size I needed. Thank you for your help

Comment: Your successful self-education validates my refusal to help, I feel a warm glow of satisfaction :-)